# How to print crystal report on multiple printers?

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I have a vb.net app which have different crystal reports. I want to print these reports to printer without opening in report viewer and i want to print these reports on 2 of my printer from which 1 of them is installed by Usb cable on my pc and another is a network printer. For network printer I can define an ip or any local network address to application if required..

Answer (score 0):

Hi first you should name these printers

```
        strSQL = "your select statement"
        Dim crptDV As New ReportDocument()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, SqlCon)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim path As String //Report Path
        crptDV.Load(path & "\reports\ReportName.rpt")
        End If

        crptDV.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName1
        crptDV.PrintToPrinter(1, True, 0, 0)

        crptDV.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName2
        crptDV.PrintToPrinter(1, True, 0, 0)
        crptDV.Close()
        crptDV.Dispose()
```