# How to print crystal report to 2 printers at once

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have vbnet application which have one crystal report print. I need to print it to 2 printers. I must show dialog for selecting printers.
Which event i need to use to call dialog form for choosing printers, and can i make number of copies

I found problem like this on [How to print crystal report on multiple printers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679943/how-to-print-crystal-report-on-multiple-printers)